# roscd can't find newly created packages (Win10/WSL)

Tags: catkin, ros-lunar, roscd, windows10, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've already read half the internet, here's what's wrong:
Packages created with catkin_create_pkg in a catkin workspace can't be found by roscd, therefore roslaunch etc. don't work either.
I already found out that the path to the workspace is missing in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, that might be the problem.
Here's what I already tried:

- Setting up a new workspace on the same level as the old one. Result: Nothing better.
- manipulating the .bashrc and ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Result: Spaces in the path to the workspace are deleted, although I used them with escape characters. So the path is incorrect and I get the adequate error.
- Creating a new plain package in the workspace/src, problem as described
- I've sourced the devel/setup.bash a million times, that doesn't fix it.
- Restarting the console permanently (always sourcing setup.bash afterwards)

Also, when trying to launch something (that worked in the exact same workspace before!), I get the error

```
[] is neither a launch file in package [] nor is [] a launch file name.
```

My setup is kind of complicated: My workspace is in a OneDrive-synced folder (Win10 file system), which is then mounted using WSL to have a Linux environment for ROS development.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300751/roscd-can%27t-find-newly-created-packages-(win10/wsl)/) by [totalnewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/37015/totalnewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Result: Spaces in the path to the workspace are deleted [..]

This is a problem (the spaces). See #q124906 fi. Afaik, this has not been resolved (but I could be wrong, [ros/ros#94](https://github.com/ros/ros/pull/94) seems to address at least part of the `rosbash` problems).

> My setup is kind of complicated: My workspace is in a OneDrive-synced folder (Win10 file system), which is then mounted using WSL to have a Linux environment for ROS development.

This is also not a typical setup and especially the "onedrive synced" part is worrying me. What does that do to your file permissions? File permissions on all files need to be correct, or binaries won't run and all sorts of other problems can come up.

I would strongly recommend you try to get a baseline by replicating your setup on a regular Ubuntu installation (perhaps a VM).

If that works while you're following the same workflow, it's more than likely that either WSL and/or your OneDrive setup is interfering.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-16**:
Also note: WSL is not a supported platform for ROS, and you are bound to run into issues.

I'm not sure it is a good environment to start learning ROS in.

See #q238646 for a related Q&A.

**Comment by [totalnewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/37015/totalnewbie/) on 2018-08-20**:
In the end, I set up a VM with Linux, which isn't ideal on a not-so-powerful portable machine for sure, but at least ROS works adequately. Thanks.